# Running as Admin, How do I check if some windows account has permissions to read a directory?

Tags: c#, security, directory

I only got the account username (DOMAIN\USER).
The check also has to take into account the user's groups.
I'd like to use [this sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/UserFileAccessRights.aspx), but I can't figure out how to get a WindowsIdentity only from a username without his password.

Answer (score 2):

Whole problematics of getting effective rights for some folder or file is rather complex.
But you don't need to get WindowsIdentity from username and domain name. For reading effective rights it is enough to have SID of the user you are checking.

There is a class NTAccount which takes exactly what you have - username and domain, that can be easily translated to the SecurityIdentifier, which represents exactly one SID.

There classes can be found in System.Security.Principal namespace.

```
NTAccount ntaccount = new NTAccount("domain", "username");
SecurityIdentifier identifier =
    (SecurityIdentifier)ntaccount.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
```

In this way you can translate username (with or without domain) to the SID which can be then used for determining to which groups this user belongs (recursively) and then you can easily read access rights using FileSecurity class (from FileInfo) and its method GetAccessRules.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of following code:

```
DirectorySecurity security = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl();
AuthorizationRuleCollection authCollection = security.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(System.Security.Principal.NTAccount));

var username = (from FileSystemAccessRule rule in authCollection
                where rule.IdentityReference.Value == "domain\\username"
                select rule).ToList();
```

Comment: One problem I can think of with this is that the accounts in the access rules might be groups, so you will need to determine if the user in question belongs to one or more of the groups.

Comment: This is exactly the problem. This code doesn't take into account the user's groups. To do this I'll need a WindowsIdentity (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Might be this can be a bit of help. Adding a current user to allow permission to access the folder. Though should be used carefully.
http://www.redmondpie.com/applying-permissions-on-any-windows-folder-using-c/

Answer (score 0):

What if you take the inverse approach?  If user does not have access (via user name) you can get the group memberships and check their access...

```
private StringCollection GetUserGroupMembership(string strUser)
{
    StringCollection groups = new StringCollection();
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry obEntry = new DirectoryEntry(
            "LDAP://CN=users,DC=example,DC=com");
        DirectorySearcher srch = new DirectorySearcher(obEntry, 
            "(sAMAccountName=" + strUser + ")");
        SearchResult res = srch.FindOne();
        if (null != res)
        {
            DirectoryEntry obUser = new DirectoryEntry(res.Path);
            // Invoke Groups method.
            object obGroups = obUser.Invoke("Groups");
            foreach (object ob in (IEnumerable)obGroups)
            {
                // Create object for each group.
                DirectoryEntry obGpEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ob);
                groups.Add(obGpEntry.Name);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Trace.Write(ex.Message);
    }
    return groups;
}
```

From http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/usergroupmembership.aspx

Now that you have the groups, you can do a join on the items returned from the directoryInfo and see if any of the user's groups has access to the directory.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

There is a WindowsIdentity constructor that only takes a UPN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/td3046fc.aspx

It does have a few infrastructure requirements as it relies on Kerberos.

Answer (score 0):

Any chance you can do the group membership check by execing [ifmember.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=07C2F6D7-815E-4FA0-9043-4E4635CCD417&displaylang=en&displaylang=en) and testing error levels? (ifmember is also in the 2003 resource kit)

Also, just a heads up, this can't be done reliably without actually logging the user in.

Per http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772184.aspx

> "The Effective Permissions tool only
>   produces an approximation of the
>   permissions that a user has. The
>   actual permissions the user has may be
>   different because permissions can be
>   granted or denied based on how a user
>   logs on. This logon-specific
>   information cannot be determined by
>   the Effective Permissions tool if the
>   user is not logged on; therefore, the
>   effective permissions it displays
>   reflect only those permissions
>   specified by the user or group and not
>   the permissions specified by the
>   logon.
>
> For example, if a user is connected to
>   this computer through a shared folder,
>   then the logon for that user is marked
>   as a network logon. Permissions can be
>   granted or denied to the Network
>   well-known SID, which the connected
>   user receives, so a user has different
>   permissions when logged on locally
>   than when logged on over a network. "

Answer (score -2):

Here's some code I hacked to work with domain\user (originally from codeproject). I abandoned it as "flawed" (just didn't like trying to reimplement an check that only the OS really knows the answer too). I also don't recall if I got anywhere with any serious sort of testing of it. I'm sure it doesn't handle explicit rights granted to a user (rather than a group) and I was uncertain as to whether the code handled deny rights.

```
class UserAccessRights
{

    /// /// This code was written by Bruce Hatt
    /// Code obtained from : http://www.codeproject.com/useritems/UserFileAccessRights.asp
    /// 
    /// This class Contains a simple answer to a 
    /// potentially complicated question "Can I read this file or can I write to this file?"
    /// 
    /// Using the "rule of least privilege", one must check not only is access granted but 
    /// is it denied at any point including a possibly recursive check of groups.
    /// 
    /// For this simple check, a look at the user and immediate groups are only checked.
    /// 
    /// This class could be expanded to identify if the applicable allow/deny rule
    /// was explicit or inherited
    /// 

    private string _path;
    //private WindowsIdentity _principal;
    private SecurityIdentifier _principalSid;

    private bool _denyAppendData = false;
    private bool _denyChangePermissions = false;
    private bool _denyCreateDirectories = false;
    private bool _denyCreateFiles = false;
    private bool _denyDelete = false;
    private bool _denyDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = false;
    private bool _denyExecuteFile = false;
    private bool _denyFullControl = false;
    private bool _denyListDirectory = false;
    private bool _denyModify = false;
    private bool _denyRead = false;
    private bool _denyReadAndExecute = false;
    private bool _denyReadAttributes = false;
    private bool _denyReadData = false;
    private bool _denyReadExtendedAttributes = false;
    private bool _denyReadPermissions = false;
    private bool _denySynchronize = false;
    private bool _denyTakeOwnership = false;
    private bool _denyTraverse = false;
    private bool _denyWrite = false;
    private bool _denyWriteAttributes = false;
    private bool _denyWriteData = false;
    private bool _denyWriteExtendedAttributes = false;


    private bool _allowAppendData = false;
    private bool _allowChangePermissions = false;
    private bool _allowCreateDirectories = false;
    private bool _allowCreateFiles = false;
    private bool _allowDelete = false;
    private bool _allowDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = false;
    private bool _allowExecuteFile = false;
    private bool _allowFullControl = false;
    private bool _allowListDirectory = false;
    private bool _allowModify = false;
    private bool _allowRead = false;
    private bool _allowReadAndExecute = false;
    private bool _allowReadAttributes = false;
    private bool _allowReadData = false;
    private bool _allowReadExtendedAttributes = false;
    private bool _allowReadPermissions = false;
    private bool _allowSynchronize = false;
    private bool _allowTakeOwnership = false;
    private bool _allowTraverse = false;
    private bool _allowWrite = false;
    private bool _allowWriteAttributes = false;
    private bool _allowWriteData = false;
    private bool _allowWriteExtendedAttributes = false;


    public bool CanAppendData { get { return !_denyAppendData && _allowAppendData; } }
    public bool CanChangePermissions { get { return !_denyChangePermissions && _allowChangePermissions; } }
    public bool CanCreateDirectories { get { return !_denyCreateDirectories && _allowCreateDirectories; } }
    public bool CanCreateFiles { get { return !_denyCreateFiles && _allowCreateFiles; } }
    public bool CanDelete { get { return !_denyDelete && _allowDelete; } }
    public bool CanDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles { get { return !_denyDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles && _allowDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles; } }
    public bool CanExecuteFile { get { return !_denyExecuteFile && _allowExecuteFile; } }
    public bool CanFullControl { get { return !_denyFullControl && _allowFullControl; } }
    public bool CanListDirectory { get { return !_denyListDirectory && _allowListDirectory; } }
    public bool CanModify { get { return !_denyModify && _allowModify; } }
    public bool CanRead { get { return !_denyRead && _allowRead; } }
    public bool CanReadAndExecute { get { return !_denyReadAndExecute && _allowReadAndExecute; } }
    public bool CanReadAttributes { get { return !_denyReadAttributes && _allowReadAttributes; } }
    public bool CanReadData { get { return !_denyReadData && _allowReadData; } }
    public bool CanReadExtendedAttributes { get { return !_denyReadExtendedAttributes && _allowReadExtendedAttributes; } }
    public bool CanReadPermissions { get { return !_denyReadPermissions && _allowReadPermissions; } }
    public bool CanSynchronize { get { return !_denySynchronize && _allowSynchronize; } }
    public bool CanTakeOwnership { get { return !_denyTakeOwnership && _allowTakeOwnership; } }
    public bool CanTraverse { get { return !_denyTraverse && _allowTraverse; } }
    public bool CanWrite { get { return !_denyWrite && _allowWrite; } }
    public bool CanWriteAttributes { get { return !_denyWriteAttributes && _allowWriteAttributes; } }
    public bool CanWriteData { get { return !_denyWriteData && _allowWriteData; } }
    public bool CanWriteExtendedAttributes { get { return !_denyWriteExtendedAttributes && _allowWriteExtendedAttributes; } }


    /// /// Simple accessor
/*        public WindowsIdentity GetWindowsIdentity
    { 
        get { return _principal; } 
    }*/

    /// /// Simple accessor
    public String GetPath
    {
        get { return _path; }
    }


    public UserAccessRights(string path, string UserId)
    {

        if ((!String.IsNullOrEmpty(UserId)) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
        {
            NTAccount n = new NTAccount(UserId);
            _principalSid = (SecurityIdentifier)n.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

            this._path = path;

            System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(_path);
            AuthorizationRuleCollection acl = fi.GetAccessControl().GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
            for (int i = 0; i < acl.Count; i++)
            {
                System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule rule = (System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule)acl[i];
                if (_principalSid.Equals(rule.IdentityReference))
                {
                    if (System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny.Equals(rule.AccessControlType))
                    {
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.AppendData, rule)) _denyAppendData = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, rule)) _denyChangePermissions = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, rule)) _denyCreateDirectories = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, rule)) _denyCreateFiles = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Delete, rule)) _denyDelete = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, rule)) _denyDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, rule)) _denyExecuteFile = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.FullControl, rule)) _denyFullControl = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, rule)) _denyListDirectory = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Modify, rule)) _denyModify = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Read, rule)) _denyRead = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, rule)) _denyReadAndExecute = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes, rule)) _denyReadAttributes = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadData, rule)) _denyReadData = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadExtendedAttributes, rule)) _denyReadExtendedAttributes = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions, rule)) _denyReadPermissions = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Synchronize, rule)) _denySynchronize = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership, rule)) _denyTakeOwnership = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Traverse, rule)) _denyTraverse = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Write, rule)) _denyWrite = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteAttributes, rule)) _denyWriteAttributes = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteData, rule)) _denyWriteData = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteExtendedAttributes, rule)) _denyWriteExtendedAttributes = true;
                    }
                    else if (System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow.Equals(rule.AccessControlType))
                    {
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.AppendData, rule)) _allowAppendData = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, rule)) _allowChangePermissions = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, rule)) _allowCreateDirectories = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, rule)) _allowCreateFiles = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Delete, rule)) _allowDelete = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, rule)) _allowDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, rule)) _allowExecuteFile = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.FullControl, rule)) _allowFullControl = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, rule)) _allowListDirectory = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Modify, rule)) _allowModify = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Read, rule)) _allowRead = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, rule)) _allowReadAndExecute = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes, rule)) _allowReadAttributes = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadData, rule)) _allowReadData = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadExtendedAttributes, rule)) _allowReadExtendedAttributes = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions, rule)) _allowReadPermissions = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Synchronize, rule)) _allowSynchronize = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership, rule)) _allowTakeOwnership = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Traverse, rule)) _allowTraverse = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Write, rule)) _allowWrite = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteAttributes, rule)) _allowWriteAttributes = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteData, rule)) _allowWriteData = true;
                        if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteExtendedAttributes, rule)) _allowWriteExtendedAttributes = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            /*
            IdentityReferenceCollection groups = _principal.Groups;
            for (int j = 0; j < groups.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < acl.Count; i++)
                {
                    System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule rule = (System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule)acl[i];
                    if (groups[j].Equals(rule.IdentityReference))
                    {
                        if (System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Deny.Equals(rule.AccessControlType))
                        {
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.AppendData, rule)) _denyAppendData = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, rule)) _denyChangePermissions = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, rule)) _denyCreateDirectories = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, rule)) _denyCreateFiles = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Delete, rule)) _denyDelete = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, rule)) _denyDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, rule)) _denyExecuteFile = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.FullControl, rule)) _denyFullControl = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, rule)) _denyListDirectory = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Modify, rule)) _denyModify = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Read, rule)) _denyRead = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, rule)) _denyReadAndExecute = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes, rule)) _denyReadAttributes = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadData, rule)) _denyReadData = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadExtendedAttributes, rule)) _denyReadExtendedAttributes = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions, rule)) _denyReadPermissions = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Synchronize, rule)) _denySynchronize = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership, rule)) _denyTakeOwnership = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Traverse, rule)) _denyTraverse = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Write, rule)) _denyWrite = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteAttributes, rule)) _denyWriteAttributes = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteData, rule)) _denyWriteData = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteExtendedAttributes, rule)) _denyWriteExtendedAttributes = true;
                        }
                        else if (System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow.Equals(rule.AccessControlType))
                        {
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.AppendData, rule)) _allowAppendData = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ChangePermissions, rule)) _allowChangePermissions = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateDirectories, rule)) _allowCreateDirectories = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.CreateFiles, rule)) _allowCreateFiles = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Delete, rule)) _allowDelete = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles, rule)) _allowDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ExecuteFile, rule)) _allowExecuteFile = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.FullControl, rule)) _allowFullControl = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ListDirectory, rule)) _allowListDirectory = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Modify, rule)) _allowModify = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Read, rule)) _allowRead = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAndExecute, rule)) _allowReadAndExecute = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadAttributes, rule)) _allowReadAttributes = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadData, rule)) _allowReadData = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadExtendedAttributes, rule)) _allowReadExtendedAttributes = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.ReadPermissions, rule)) _allowReadPermissions = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Synchronize, rule)) _allowSynchronize = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.TakeOwnership, rule)) _allowTakeOwnership = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Traverse, rule)) _allowTraverse = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.Write, rule)) _allowWrite = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteAttributes, rule)) _allowWriteAttributes = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteData, rule)) _allowWriteData = true;
                            if (Contains(FileSystemRights.WriteExtendedAttributes, rule)) _allowWriteExtendedAttributes = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            */
        }
    }

    /// /// Simply displays all allowed rights
    /// 
    /// Useful if say you want to test for write access and find
    /// it is false;
    /// <xmp> /// UserFileAccessRights rights = new UserFileAccessRights(txtLogPath.Text);
    /// System.IO.FileInfo fi = new System.IO.FileInfo(txtLogPath.Text);
    /// if (rights.canWrite() && rights.canRead()) {
    /// lblLogMsg.Text = "R/W access";
    /// } else {
    /// if (rights.canWrite()) {
    /// lblLogMsg.Text = "Only Write access";
    /// } else if (rights.canRead()) {
    /// lblLogMsg.Text = "Only Read access";
    /// } else {
    /// lblLogMsg.CssClass = "error";
    /// lblLogMsg.Text = rights.ToString()
    /// }
    /// }
    /// 
    /// </xmp> /// 
    public override String ToString()
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (CanAppendData) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("AppendData"); }
        if (CanChangePermissions) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ChangePermissions"); }
        if (CanCreateDirectories) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("CreateDirectories"); }
        if (CanCreateFiles) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("CreateFiles"); }
        if (CanDelete) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("Delete"); }
        if (CanDeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles"); }
        if (CanExecuteFile) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ExecuteFile"); }
        if (CanFullControl) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("FullControl"); }
        if (CanListDirectory) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ListDirectory"); }
        if (CanModify) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("Modify"); }
        if (CanRead) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("Read"); }
        if (CanReadAndExecute) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ReadAndExecute"); }
        if (CanReadAttributes) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ReadAttributes"); }
        if (CanReadData) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ReadData"); }
        if (CanReadExtendedAttributes) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ReadExtendedAttributes"); }
        if (CanReadPermissions) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("ReadPermissions"); }
        if (CanSynchronize) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("Synchronize"); }
        if (CanTakeOwnership) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("TakeOwnership"); }
        if (CanTraverse) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("Traverse"); }
        if (CanWrite) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("Write"); }
        if (CanWriteAttributes) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("WriteAttributes"); }
        if (CanWriteData) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("WriteData"); }
        if (CanWriteExtendedAttributes) { if (sb.Length != 0) sb.Append(","); sb.Append("WriteExtendedAttributes"); }

        if (sb.Length == 0)
            sb.Append("None");

        return sb.ToString();
    }

    /// /// Convenience method to test if the right exists within the given rights
    public static bool Contains(FileSystemRights right, FileSystemAccessRule rule)
    {
        bool returnValue = false;
        if (rule != null)
        {
            returnValue = (((int)right & (int)rule.FileSystemRights) == (int)right);
        }
        return returnValue;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can add strings to a list and `String.Join(",", list);` in the end

Comment: @abatishchev: This is not my code originally (see codeproject comment). I just quickly mod'd it to accept user\domain (instead of a securityprincipal). I'm not even endorsing it... just sharing it warts an all :)